# How solve this erro I Get error concurent update? Firebird 3.0 Devart Ibdac

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures, firebird, devart

Need help me how solve this problem I Get error concurent update?
Delphi Unigui Web application master detail cacheupdatemode 
I have

1. MainConnection
2. ReadTransaction isolation :ReadCommited
3. WriteTransaction isolation :Snapshot

```
    masterqry ='select * from master' ,  detailqry ='select * from detail'
      autocommit:=false
      chachedupdate:=true
      localmasterdetail:=true 
      Transaction := ReadTransaction
      UpdateTransaction:=WriteTransaction
      and storedProcedure
      autocommit:=false
      chachedupdate:=false
      Transaction := ReadTransaction
      UpdateTransaction:=WriteTransaction
```

> do like this

```
masterqry.post;
detailqry.post;

try
  UpdateTransaction.start
  masterqry.commitupdates;
  detailqry.commitupdates; 
  storedProcedure.parambyname('P_ID').value:=masterqryID.value
  storedProcedure.execsql
  storedProcedure.close;
  UpdateTransaction.commit;
except
  UpdateTransaction.rollback;
  masterqry.cancelUpdates;
  detailqry.cancelUpdates;
  storedProcedure.close;
end
```

> stored procedure like this

```
ProcMasterTableUpdateBalance(ID)
begin
  update master
     set summa= (select sum(summ) from detail where masterid=:id)
  where  masterid=:id;


  update detail a
     set addamount = (select sum(summ)/0.1 from detail b where b.detailid=a.detailid and  b.masterid=:id)
  where  a.masterid=:id;

  delete from archivedetail where  masterid=:id;
  insert into archivedetail
  select * from detail where  masterid=:id;

end
```

Comment: You must commit the transaction before execute the stored procedure.

Comment: Exactly which Firebird 3 version are you using? Do you get the same problem with Firebird 2.5? If not you might have hit a bug with Firebird 3 (which btw is still in development).

Comment: @ValMarinov If all updates happen in the same transaction as the stored procedure call, than it should not be necessary to commit the transaction before calling the stored procedure.

Comment: I am not familiar with delphi, nor devart, but are you sure the stored procedure is executed with the `UpdateTransaction`? If not that could explain your problem. You might also want to consider using a trigger for what your stored procedure is doing.

Comment: How about wrong or error except transaction..  When commit before call procedure or when call procedure how rollback?

Comment: I would like to do all save master and detail and call procedure in one transaction? Is it imposible.?

Comment: @Mark Your comment answered to what you have written :)

Comment: @GoodBit Consider using a single transaction instead?

Comment: @ValMarinov So if I understand you correctly, devart/delphi will use the `ReadTransaction` for executing the stored procedure here?

Comment: ReadTransaction for read  Update Transaction for write data

Comment: That I understand, but do you realise that this problem could stem from the stored procedure being executed using the `ReadTransaction`.

Comment: FB requires an open transaction, try CommitRetaining instead:
[link](https://www.devart.com/ibdac/docs/?devart.ibdac.tibctransaction.commitretaining%28%29.htm)

Comment: @FredS In general you should avoid commit retaining like the plague.

Comment: Ok A will try delete UpdateTransaction property StoredProcedure